# Open files with prefixed with a pattern at the beginning of file name

Tags: macos, file, ventura, file-extensions

I have several files with names c.XXXX and fort.XXXX, where XXXX are arbitrary characters. I want these file types to open by default in Emacs or TextEdit. How to do it?

Comment: By definition, a file extension is a suffix at the end of a file that identifies what type of file it is.  Finder and LaunchServices uses the extension (the suffix) to map default applications, icons, quick looks, etc. to files of particular types.  You can't just re-map this on a whim.

Comment: @Allan Thank you for your reply. I am using Auto-07p, a bifurcation software, that inputs and outputs these filename patterns.

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13557/choose-a-default-app-for-opening-files-with-no-extension